# Using an IN condition for a Case When Statement Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I would like to use an IN clause with a `Case` Statement for my Oracle report.

I have a parameter which uses Jan-20, Feb-20 and so on.

When I select Apr-20, I would like to retrieve the rows for Jan-20, Feb-20, Mar-20 and Apr-20. If i select Jan-20, I would like to retrieve the rows for just Jan-20.

I'm planning on using a CASE WHEN statement.

The plan was below:

```
WHERE GL.periodname IN
CASE WHEN :Parameter = 'Jan-20' THEN 'Jan-20'
CASE WHEN :Parameter = 'Feb-20' THEN 'Jan-20'
CASE WHEN :Parameter = 'Feb-20' THEN 'Feb-20'
CASE WHEN :Parameter = 'Mar-20' THEN 'Jan-20'
CASE WHEN :Parameter = 'Mar-20' THEN 'Feb-20'
CASE WHEN :Parameter = 'Mar-20' THEN 'Mar-20'
```

and so on.

Does anyone know an alternative as this seems to only work with one WHEN clause being the same?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I think that the "IN" expects a list on the right hand side.  Maybe try  CASE WHEN :Parameter = 'Mar-28' THEN ( 'Jan-20', 'Feb-20','Mar-20')

Comment: You might also consider making a separate 2 column table that associates the periodname you want to use with each of the months to pull.  Join to this association table instead of writing a complicated case statement.

Answer (score 2):

Just convert to dates:

```
where to_date(gl.periodname, 'Mon-RR') <= to_date(:Parameter, 'Mon-RR')
```

(Note:  You might need to take the year into account as well.  That is not clear.)

I would actually recommend storing the period name as YYYY-MM format ("2020-01") rather than the way you are doing it.

Then if you pass the parameter in with the same format, you can just use string comparison:

```
where gl.PeriodName <= :Parameter
```

Answer (score 0):

Your description indicates your looking for a date range of values. Namely from Jan through the parameter month provide in the parameter. If so a Case statement will not give you what you want as it can only return a single value. Since you are looking for a date range convert your period name column and the parameter to dates. [See fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=d3e3af307c4cb6295798a60d48e8a2cf).

```
with parameter as
     ( select to_date('&MonYr','Mon-rr') ep from dual )
   , period ( start_period, end_period) as 
     ( select trunc(ep,'year'), ep from parameter )
select period_name  
  from gl
  join period 
    on to_date(period_name,'Mon-rr') between start_period and end_period;
```

I would go a step further than @Gordon and just store this as DATE. If you really need the Mon_rr format that often then add it a a virtual column. So:

```
create table gl (
       period_date date
     , period_name varchar2(16) 
          generated always as (to_char(period_date, 'Mon-rr')) virtual );
```